# How to get Blob (or file) from firebase image url using react and Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage, fetch-api

I have a website where I have a bunch of images on display that have been uploaded to Firebase Storage.

Now, I would like to add functionality to resize and save a copy of the image, if one does not already exist. Thus, I am trying to fetch the image from the image url, convert it to a blob (or File), resize and then upload it again.

However, the fetch method in react returns an error (TypeError: Failed to fetch), when using the firebase url.

**URL:** https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/gragripen-mit.appspot.com/o/files%2F4e8c089a-8e0b-4179-bef8-45fc6096a312_profileImage?alt=media&token=6965cfed-9c22-4b19-8953-778b145d7be9

**Code: **

```
let blob = await fetch(url).then( r=> r.blob())
```

**Error:**
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Can I anyone help me figure out what to do, or if I'm missing something?

I have tried a few different ways of handling the url (splitting it at the "?"), but I either get the same result or I get a blob that holds a json of the file information.

Comment: You're trying to fetch an image from firebase storage, but the url you're using is not directly accessible due to FS security, so use the Firebase SDK instead.

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Thank you! Could you please expand on that?

Comment: What will happen when you do like this ```fetch('FirebaseImageUrl').then(r => r.blob()).then(blob => {  // Do something with the blob }).catch(error => { console.error('Failed to fetch image', error); });``` ?

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation The URL in the question is a so-called download URL, which is accessible by anyone and not guarded by Firebase's security rules.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I just assume that maybe the actual image is private and not shareable and the url in the post is just a sample only.